# How do you create an aframe button

Tags: button, aframe

Does anyone know how to create a button in aframe

Comment: What do you mean (button for Vive Controllers? Gamepad? Mouse?), and what have you tried so far? Using the A-Frame [cursor component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.2.0/components/cursor.html) with any object lets you execute JavaScript when that object is clicked.

Comment: i mean like an aframe tag that you can use to create buttons that loads a new screen. And the best i could get was to do it with a picture.

Comment: Right but, if what you want isn't a picture that looks like a button, what sort of button are you going for? Like a small 3D cylinder that moves slightly when it's clicked? And you already have the "loads a new screen" part figured out? Your question is pretty vague sorry.

Comment: I guess I could try the cylinder and yes I already know how to make it load a new screen

Answer (score 1):

One way to create a button with A-Frame would be to use the `<a-box>` primitive combined with a cursor. The following is a simple demo:

```
<a-scene>
    <a-entity position="0 .6 4">
        <a-camera>
            <a-entity id="mycursor" cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 500; max-distance: 30;"
            position="0 0 -5"
            geometry="primitive: ring"
            material="color: blue; shader: flat">
            </a-entity>
        </a-camera>
    </a-entity>

    <!-- "button" -->
    <a-entity id="refresh-button" geometry="primitive: box" material="color: red" position="0 0 -2"></a>
</a-scene>

<script>
    document.querySelector('#refresh-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Refresh stuff would go here!
    });
</script>
```

When the cursor focuses on the "button", the `click` event would fire.  To add text to the button, you can use this component:

https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-text-component

Lastly, if you're looking for a more traditional "button", you could simply float a `<button>` element over the canvas or Iframe if you're embedding.

Comment: If you want the button to be integrated into the scene, floating the button won't work as it won't display on VR headsets nor be shaded. And https://github.com/bryik/aframe-bmfont-text-component is a great text solution.

Comment: what about creating a box and positioning text in front of it.

Comment: This worked for me.
 
      <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gasolin/aframe-href-component/gh-pages/build.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="webvr.js"></script>
      <script src="https://rawgit.com/ngokevin/aframe-text-component/master/dist/aframe-text-component.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<a-scene>
   <a-box width="1" height="0.4" position="0 0 0" depth="0.0" color="red">
      <a-entity  text="text: What's up" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" color="blue"
      position="-0.3 0.01 0">
        
      </a-entity>
    </a-box>
    </a-scene>

Answer (score 0):

i like https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-event-set-component for the hover event. And i give my cursor an attribute (data clickable) and then i say the raycaster he should just trigger entities with the attribute. If you want to let something just be clickable if you for example enter the vr-mode simply remove the dataclickable attribute. Scene looks like this:

```
<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" raycaster="objects: [data-clickable]">

        <a-image id="button" data-clickable visible="true" position="2 1.75 -0.2" height="0.5" width="0.5" rotation="0 90 0" onclick="dosomething()" event-set__enter="_event: mouseenter;  width: 0.53; height: 0.53;"
            event-set__leave="_event: mouseleave;  width: 0.5; height: 0.5;"></a-image>

    <a-camera>
      <a-cursor id="curseid" raycaster="objects: [data-clickable]"</a-cursor>
    </a-camera>

</a-scene>
```

If you want that a button works just if something happend give him the attribute later:

```
document.getElementById('button').setAttribute('data-clickable', '');
```

If you done with the button use:

```
document.getElementById('button').setAttribute('visible', 'false');
document.getElementById('button').removeAttribute('data-clickable');
```

If you want that the cursor just triggers button if you for example enter vr-mode, change the raycaster="objects: .notclickable" and then give him later with this line his attribute back:

```
document.getElementById('curseid').setAttribute('raycaster', 'objects: [data-clickable]');
```

This is for now my way to do buttons, maybe there is a smarter way. I hope this helped a bit :D

Comment: and i change scenes like this: wrap all elements of one scene in an a-entity, then set visible to false of the one wrapper and set it to visible = true on your other scene to show it. Don´t forget to remove data-clickable attribute or the elements are just invicible but still gets triggered. Maybe also change the source of your a-sky if you use that to change the environment.