# Is there a better way to create a button in AFrame?

Tags: button, aframe, webvr

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987416/how-do-you-create-an-aframe-button) answer to how to create a 3-dimensional button in AFrame, but I was wondering if there was a better way to accomplish this. If there isn't, could somebody please clarify how the rotation/position attributes for the text work (e.g. where the axis of rotation is, where the position is based around relative to the cube, etc.). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which implementation of text you are using. WebGL has no inherent concept of layout like the 2D web. There are upcoming implementations of text which will make it easier to layout and size.

For now, if a text implementation doesn't have any concept of layout, I would use the A-Frame Inspector (`<ctrl> + <alt> + i`) to manually place your text.

If you want automatic layout in relations to a mesh, you could also try computing the bounding box of the mesh and the text, and automatically centering/aligning the text.